# Failed to load bean class; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using spring java based configuration in web app. I have an issue.

In my config file I am doing import and getting some other java config files.

When I run my test cases all the test cases are passing.In my test cases I am using Aplication to get the bean. I dont have any problem there. But When I tell it to run on server it is saying that one of the config es doesn't exist. So import is not working. But when I do ctrl+click on the code I am able to travel into that config code.

I am using TomCat Version 7.0 and Using maven I am getting all other dependencies.

Stack trace is as below:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplication
Jul 18, 2012 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.Standard Start
SEVERE:      to   of      
org.springframework.web..Loader
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStore: Failed to load bean :     
com.Hello.World.HelloWorldConfig; nested  is     
java.io.FileNotFound:  path resource [com/hello/configs/MyConfig.] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationPostProcessor.java:267)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationPostProcessor.java:203)
at org.springframework..support.AbstractApplication.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplication.java:622)
at org.springframework..support.AbstractApplication.refresh(AbstractApplication.java:451)
at org.springframework.web..Loader.configureAndRefreshWebApplication(Loader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web..Loader.initWebApplication(Loader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web..Loader.(Loader.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Standard.Start(Standard.java:4779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Standard.startInternal(Standard.java:5273)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFound:  path resource [com/hello/configs/MyConfig.] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.PathResource.getInputStream(PathResource.java:157)
at org.springframework.core.type.reading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
at org.springframework.core.type.reading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.reading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
at org.springframework.core.type.reading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationParser.processImport(ConfigurationParser.java:317)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationParser.doProcessConfiguration(ConfigurationParser.java:228)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationParser.processConfiguration(ConfigurationParser.java:149)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:126)
at org.springframework..annotation.ConfigurationPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationPostProcessor.java:263)
... 16 more
Jul 18, 2012 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.Standard startInternal
SEVERE: Error Start
Jul 18, 2012 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.Standard startInternal
SEVERE:  [/helloWorld] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 18, 2012 4:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.Application log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplication
```

And the config  as follows

```
@Configuration
@Import({MyConfig.})
public  HelloWorldConfig {

@Autowired
public MyName myName;

@Bean
public MyModel myModel() {
    MyModel bean = new MyModel();
    bean.setMyName(myName);     
    return bean;
}
}
```

I am not able to figure out what I am missing.

**UPDATE**:

I noticed that when I close the MyName project in eclipse it is not working and when I open it project is working. But MyModel project should not depend on myname project on local disk. I created a jar for Myname project and pushed it into central repository. So it should get the jar from repo. So i am not able to get understand what it has to do with my local disk content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you are missing MyConfig.class on the classpath.

But are you sure to import `MyConfig`? It's `MyModel` that you use. Second, why do you use a array parameter for `@Import`?

Either way, it looks like a deployment problem and may be unrelated to the import annotation. So check you projects settings to see if the sought class is really exported.

Comment: Hey Arne,I noticed that when I close the MyName project in eclipse it is not working and when I open it project is working. But MyModel project should not depend on myname project on local disk. I created a jar for Myname project and pushed it into local repository

Comment: @ravi I'm quite sure it's not deployed. To be sure, check the deployment directory.

Comment: Can you be more elobarate. I dont understand what do you mean by deployment directory.

Comment: The deployment directory is the directory where all your application's files are copied before it starts. assuming you use wtp in Eclipse, select "Debug Configurations..." from the "Run" menu. Select the debug configuration for your project, click on the "Arguments" tab and lookup the `-Dwtp.deploy` parameter in the "VM Arguments". It points to the directory where all your projects files are stored. Check if your JAR is there. If not try to find the reason.

Comment: you are right. there is no Myname jar file. I tried adding one more jar file. It showed up . But Myname jar file is still not present. Any guesses why this can happen?

Comment: Your are using maven, may be it's eclipse integration? I do not have much experience with this, apart from a few months trouble in a specific customer's project. I recommend to double check settings, poms, any logs of the deployment process etc. And don't forget to close and reopen eclipse - no kidding - I had such a "maven-i-don't-get-it" problem got fixed by that after two hours.